# How can I update to jdk and jre 7?

Tags: java, openjdk

I've been using jdk6 on ubuntu 12.04. I was trying to update my jdk to 7. I installed jdk7 and also removed jdk6.
Now my javac version is 1.7.0_03. but my java version is still 1.6.0_24. So I got UnsupportedClassVersionError while trying ro run my java project.
How can I update my java?!

Comment: Possible duplicate http://askubuntu.com/questions/136202/java-jre-will-not-install-in-ubuntu-12-04 if you don't need version 6, you can purge it before installing version 7

Answer (score 1):

To install Java 7:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre
```

[image: Install via the software center]

```
sudo apt-get install icedtea-7-plugin
```

[image: Install via the software center]

- [How do I install Java?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48468/how-do-i-install-java)